# Image glow on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This css language is all to new to me , i just have a few questions if i may . 
id like the image to glow around it , or go from a lighter opacity  to its original color like so --> (output.jsbin.com/vahaseduka) // codepen.io/anon/pen/ilqnb (THE CAMERA IMAGE IS AN ACTUAL IMAGE I WILL BE USING)

I used someone's sample code to achieve this effect.

I am satisfied with the image besides two qualities.  *Upon hover a boxed border will come up like so ---> i59.tinypic.com/2dmayyv.jpg .... i don't like that frame (box) upon hover , HOW MAY I REMOVE THIS ?

Also as we see I cannot re-size the photo to size as id like without the scroll bars ? I am using wix.com to build the site, it is a compatibility issue with the site ? Or, should I downsize the image in Photoshop?

the code for this project is :

```css
    #ex5 {
      width: 700px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      min-height: 300px;
      background: transbox;
    }
    #ex5 img {
      margin: 0px;
      opacity: 0.8;
      border: 0px transbox #eee;
      /*Transition*/
      -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
      -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
      -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
      /*Reflection*/
      -webkit-box-reflect: below 0px -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(transparent), color-stop(.7, transparent), to(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)));
    }
    #ex5 img:hover {
      opacity: 1;
      /*Reflection*/
      -webkit-box-reflect: below 0px -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(transparent), color-stop(.7, transparent), to(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4)));
      /*Glow*/
      -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 50px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
      -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 50px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
      box-shadow: 0px 0px 50px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset=utf-8 />
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <!--[if IE]>
      <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  <style>
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="ex5">
    <img src="http://i57.tinypic.com/2poqqsn.png">

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I suggest you to visit [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) page and read the [formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) guide.

Comment: What browser are you using, because I see a few differences depending on the browser you use. Internet explorer is notorious for adding scroll bar to images that aren't sized properly.

Comment: [Try this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6233922/how-do-you-make-an-image-or-button-glow-when-you-mouse-over-using-javascript-or)

Comment: hello and thank you very much . ive been reading loads of tutorials from you guys and would love to have a team as such as you guys . i hope we may all help each other on here ...   ive read most of the guide you gave but i must say its all gibberish to me , i have to find myself looking for a definition for every other word , lol .  i am using the chrome browser btw

Comment: the last link you have provided i have seen before i joined the forum . the example of the users image was not provided , being i cant see what he was trying to accomplish . I did look at the other effects , although cool there not what im looking to do .

Answer (score 0):

The scrollbars appear because the border is effectively changing the box sizing. I recommend you reading about [the box model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box_model).

As for your particular problem, try adding `box-sizing: border-box;` to your image `#ex5 img`, it may help you avoid those scrollbars, which appear because you are setting the width/height from your CSS. Other hacky/ugly way to avoid them is setting `overflow: hidden;` which may crop your image near the borders and give undesireable results.

Comment: i have tried the codes , got no results , maybe i have in putted them wrong... i am currently reading the tutorial i will take what i have learned , apply it and present something back to the forum .... just want to say i greatly appreciate you guys

Answer (score 0):

Clear This style

```
border: 0px transbox #eee;
```

and assign height attribute to image tag (#ex5 img in your case)some what like

```
height:150px;  //your figure
```

if problem again please inform

This link will help you to be a good web designer http://www.w3schools.com/

Comment: I would like to say i know it may be a bit discouraging trying to teach someone like myself  but i am very eager . when it comes to web design all i know is the wix platform , nothing about html css and these other languages. i do try to do as much research and trial and error before i blurb these questions but most times im just in need of a little more undivided attention , or something maybe even more subject and or topic specific . with that being said . The size option was a huge move for me it may take forever being i cant just stretch it but i may now adjust the image size that i want

Comment: i am also using a the chrome browser . ***

Comment: Granted...I want to know , current status about your code.Is it works or not.

Comment: Go through the link given above..Gud luck

Comment: i was able to resize all my images and have them go from a lighter opicity back to regular opicity upon hover ... I most definitely appreciate that link sir ,  my next question would be how to remove canvas area (that would also get rid of the scroll bars? ), given the link about "the box model" i understand why its taking so much canvas  area but i cannot formulate it as a command, and the codes i was given didnt make a difference in my image , ill use that site for reference :))) i really appreciate this all guys .

Comment: You can search every thing up to your wish at the w3school.com.All you want to do is just search the name or tag whatever that you want to know..        And Could you please update the current status of your  codes.I will try my on way to help yoou..

Comment: im looking and looking vijay , but i cannot find how to add a "bounce upon hover" animation to my current html code.... idk how to insert it but if we look at NUMBER 5 on here ---> www.developerdrive .com/2015/01/8-simple-css-hover-effects/ we can see what id like to do

Answer (score 0):

Just create this styles to your web page like

```
<style>
   @keyframes bounce {
0%, 20%, 60%, 100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0);
}

40% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-20px);
    transform: translateY(-20px);
}

80% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-10px);
    transform: translateY(-10px);
    }
}

img:hover {   //you may replace button with any tag
    animation: bounce 1s;
}

</style>

<div id="ex5">
    <img id="img1" class="anim" src="http://i57.tinypic.com/2poqqsn.png">
    <img id="img2" class="anim" src="http://i57.tinypic.com/2poqqsn.png">
    <br>
    <img id="img3" src="http://i57.tinypic.com/2poqqsn.png">
    <img id="img4" src="http://i57.tinypic.com/2poqqsn.png">

</div>

<html>
```

I just replace the style

```
button:hover{..} <--with -->
img:hower{..}
```

But remember dude,img,button,div are tags.

suppose, think that you have so many img tags in your page.

So that the hover effect will affect entire img on the web page.

i recommend you to create a style defined by class or id.

```
 /*Eg:-
  for class, use a dot sign before the class name which you want to give  style*/

.anim:hover {  
   animation: bounce 1s;
}

/*for ID, use # sign before the name of ID any name of your ID defined on your html page(i define 4 id, img1,img2,img3,img4) */


   #img3:hover {  /*It animates only img named #img3 */
   animation: bounce 1s;
}

/*for tag, use nothing ,only name of tag that you want to apply style*/

.anim:hover {  
   animation: bounce 1s;
}
```

This is the way for creating styles.I updated this link.Go through it
or

Try this in JSfiddle [Click to see in Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/S9WQv/441/embedded/result/)

Inform me if any trouble
Nice day...

Comment: id like to give you the code im trying to apply the affect to but apparently its too big ....  i believe we misunderstood each other,    id like to make an image bounce not make a bouncing button , does the same technique apply? ,  i have tried to add .-- > @keyframes bounce {
0%, 20%, 60%, 100% { ...  etc up to * </style> *   under every 
</style> * command i seen  but nothing

Comment: trutechnology.wix .com/ttred thats what im working on , id like these objects to glow as such , but bounce as well upon hower.

Comment: Sorry for the bouncing button..and Thanks for this appreciation.I edited the code.Go and try this out.

Comment: You may change ID or class name of that hover style and see the result,also I updated that fiddle link with code..gud luck

Comment: I go through the link you had given.Is that you designed.amazing.But I cannot find styles in that web page.Please give me the source code,If its large file send via mail ,I will try to rectify the mistakes.

Comment: Actually Here is your problem<!--[if IE]>
  <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->                                                                                                                        This <!--...--> is comment- means The codes you written inside this bracs <!--...--> will not execute.So clear this comment and also clear the if[IE].. [endif] statement.Try this ..                                                                         Or paste
  <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>

Comment: hello vijay ! i have cleared ....   <!--[if IE]> <script src="html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></…; <![endif] .... i added everything in between the two </style> commands ...   thank you for the tutorial on creating styles , after adding the correct ID , the images were bouncing away !!  vijay id really like to credit you on the site once its finished . ill be sure to keep in contact ! my email is trutechnology@aol.com

Comment: if you may please email me . i am working on adding speech bubbles to it . with your help i was able to accomplish this already :) , but i do not like the design and do have a few tweaks id like to make. email is above .